# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file but no encoding declared

Tags: python

In my terminal window, I am getting a syntax error for a code and I'm not sure what the problem is. I just need a second pair of eyes so double-check for me.

Code:

```
from modeller import *
from modeller.automodel import *


env = environ() 
aln = alignment(env) 
mdl = model(env, file=‘5ZEO’, model_segment = ('FIRST:A','LAST:A'))
aln.append_model(mdl, align_codes=‘5ZEOA', atom_files=‘5ZEO’) 
aln.append(file='target.seq', align_codes='target')
aln.salign() 
aln.write(file='target-5ZEO.ali', alignment_format='PIR')
```

```
Error:   File "align.py", line 7
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file align.py on line 7, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Comment: @ggorlen so how I'm suppose to show it for help?

Comment: @ggorlen mm ok.

Comment: Error seems self-explanatory. Looks like you have rich text quotes? Replace those with ASCII quotes. Did you copy and paste this code from some PDF or rich text document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've pasted, you can tell where it's going wrong when the syntax coloring gets all weird.

You're using typographical quotes in the statement

```
aln.append_model(mdl, align_codes=‘5ZEOA', atom_files=‘5ZEO’)
```

-- that needs to be

```
aln.append_model(mdl, align_codes='5ZEOA', atom_files='5ZEO')
```

instead.